# Split string by space and space as delimiter in Oracle with regexp_substr

Tags: sql, oracle

I had one requirement like one string will be there like "**FATALITY, BODY SYS, TEAM BUILDING EVENT.THE EMPLOYEE WAS PARTICIPATING IN A TEAM BUILDING EVENT WHEN HE SUFFERED A HEART ATTACK. THE EVENT WAS FATAL.**" and I have another LOOK up table to match the certain word in the above string .If any word matches from this this sentence then the matching word should only need to return other wise null valves need to be there. This can be done with regexp_substr but not able to match the pattern.

input string :FATALITY, BODY SYS, TEAM BUILDING EVENT.THE EMPLOYEE WAS PARTICIPATING IN A TEAM BUILDING EVENT WHEN HE SUFFERED A **HEART** ATTACK. THE EVENT WAS **FATAL**.

Expected o/p: HEART,FATAL --this heart and fatal will be in lookup table.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a simple `INSTR` function?

```
SQL> with string (id, col) as
  2    (select 1, 'FATALITY, BODY SYS, TEAM BUILDING EVENT.THE EMPLOYEE WAS PARTICIPATING IN A TEAM BUILDING EVENT WHEN HE SUFFERED A HEART ATTACK. THE EVENT WAS FATAL.' from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'THERE IS ONLY HEART IN HERE' from dual),
  4  lookup (word) as
  5    (select 'HEART' from dual union all
  6     select 'FATAL' from dual
  7    )
  8  select s.id,
  9    listagg(l.word, ', ') within group (order by l.word) result
 10  from string s join lookup l on instr(s.col, l.word) > 0
 11  group by s.id;

        ID RESULT
---------- ----------------------------------------
         1 FATAL, HEART
         2 HEART

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks For quick response, it keep on running  when I put actual table and column names in above  query.

Comment: You're welcome. If tables are large, it'll take time. As you can see, on a simple test case it works OK. *Maybe* if you used SQL Text (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ccref/oracle-text-SQL-statements-and-operators.html) options it would run better, but - I'm not good at it.

Comment: Just want to know any way like this,

Comment: select regexp_substr(REPLACE(REPLACE('500 Oracle Parkway. Redwood Shores ,CA', ',', ' '), '.', ''),'match pattern'
                    ,1 -- Start here
                    ,2 -- return 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. match
                    ,null
                    ,1 -- return 1st sub exp
                    )
  from dual;